# How to append array into data from ipcRenderer

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vue-component

I am trying to get select the list of files(path) from directory and display it on the DOM,but in order to display data i have to first assign in vuejs data object.

mainRenderer

```
ipcMain.on("channel1", (e, args) => {
  const files = getFileFromUserSelection();
  e.reply("channel1", files); // sending to channel1 in app.vue
});

const getFileFromUserSelection = () => {
  const files = dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ["multiSelections"]
  });
  if (!files) return;
  return files;
};
```

App.Vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="file in files">{{file}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";

//this gets files from the main process 
ipcRenderer.on("channel1", (e, files) => {
  console.log(files); // i want this file into data:function()
});

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      files: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clicked: function() {
      ipcRenderer.send("channel1", "open dialog to getFiles from user");
    }
  }
};


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `beforeCreate` hook on the `Vue`component in order to hydrate the `data` property:

```
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      files: []
    };
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    ipcRenderer.on("channel1", (e, files) => {
      this.files = files
    });
  },
  methods: {
    clicked: function() {
      ipcRenderer.send("channel1", "open dialog to getFiles from user");
    }
  }
};
```

Note that, of course, you cannot interact directly with the files array until you know it's been hydrated, so a computed getter here may be of some use to you, or just use `files.length`.